# Detect Ext.menu.Menu close/ outfocus

Tags: javascript, extjs

May i know how to detect when `Ext.menu.Menu` is `closed` / `outfocus`.

i would like to have some action done when the menu closed or outfocused.

```js
Ext.create( 'Ext.menu.Menu', 
  { width     : 100
  , margin    : '0 0 10 0'
  , floating  : false
  , renderTo  : Ext.getBody()
  , items : 
     [ { text : 'regular item 1' }
     , { text : 'regular item 2' }
     , { text : 'regular item 3' }
     ]
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use listeners to execute some logic when a supported event occurs. For example to detect if the menu was hidden (like a context menu dismissed) you can use the `hide` listener.

Add this to the `Ext.create` config of your menu:

```js
listeners: {
    hide: function (sender, eOpts) {
        console.log('menu hide listener invoked');
    }
}
```

For a complete list of available listeners on `Ext.menu.Menu`, check the documentation for the [classic](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.menu.Menu.html#events) and for the [modern](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.menu.Menu.html#events) framework.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Also the event for loosing focus is [blur](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.menu.Menu.html#event-blur)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check "Collapse" config which accepts boolean value.
Also, on Collapse you can write your logic

```
listeners: {
    collapse: function(panel, eOpts) {
        console.log('panel', panel.getCollapsed());
    }
}
```